# Alternativa a numpy.append para acelerar el algoritmo

Tags: numpy, python-3.7

El asunto es que tengo un super-array de numpy de ~1GB, donde cada item pasa por un algoritmo y después se guarda en otro super-array con **append**, el cual tiene una manera de trabajar que no me gusta. A ver, si le digo que añada un item al final del array, ¿porqué me devuelve una copia modificada y no me modifica la original?¿Entonces porqué duplica el array, sin necesidad? Es que no lo entiendo, si numpy busca el rendimiento, con esto se han dado bien. Este es el código:

```
import numpy as np

a_original # Array original numpy de una dimensión con los datos, dtype=np.uint8
a_final = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8) # Array donde se pasan los items

for i,item in enumerate(a_original):
    ''' Aquí se pasa el item por el algoritmo '''
    a_final = np.append(a_final, item) # Se añade al final del array
```

Lo que hago es sobrescribir la variable **a_final** para no duplicar la memoria. Pero esta forma de trabajar que tiene **append** ralentiza demasiado el proceso para archivos grandes. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de hacer esto?

Comment: No, el array original no tiene los items procesados. Se procesan en el bucle y se añaden al a_final modificados.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "vectorizar"? Desconozco el número de items que tendrá el a_final, si no lo habría hecho en la declaración, porque es más rápido, ya lo sé.

Comment: Vectorizar es aplicar operaciones al array en su conjunto (con operaciones que lleva NumPy a cabo a bajo nivel en código C), por ejemplo, cuando haces  `array += 1` para sumar 1 a todos los elementos del array en vez de `for i in range(len(array)): array[i] += 1`.

Comment: Con lo de conocer el número de items al final no me refiero "al final final", me refiero a si partiendo de un a_original y un a_final con contenido o no previo, antes de iniciar el ciclo sabes que se van a agregar un elemento o dos o lo que sea por cada elemento de `a_original`. Si es así, puedes intentar reservar memoria con resize lo cual (aunque tuviera que realojar el array en memoria por falta de espacio contiguo) es mucho más eficiente. El problma es si por cada elemento agregamos 1 2 o ningún item en función del algoritmo...

Comment: Entiendo. No sé pueden aplicar operaciones generales para todos por igual, ojalá, jajaa, tampoco sé de antemano si cada item del array original, equivaldrá a otro solamente del final. El algoritmo lo que hace reducir los items repetidos en otro para el array final. Si no se repiten es uno por uno.

Comment: Aunque el algoritmo podría mejorarse un poco, creo que el problema está en la sentencia append, toma demasiados recursos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un array en NumPy, en C o Fortran... es por definición un conjunto de datos que ocupan posiciones contiguas en memoria. Esto es importante porque permite realizar operaciones de forma muy eficiente sobre los datos, por ejemplo es básico para poder usar aritmética de punteros.

Cuando defines un array de tamaño N para un tipo de dato con tamaño M, NumPy le pide al sistema operativo que le reserve un fragmento de memoria con tamaño de al menos  N x M bytes para poder localizar el array.

El SO asignará el espacio que le parezca mejor, lo mismo tenemos 2 GB de memoria libre (no asignada) tras el array (cosa que puede cambiar en cualquier momento además) o tenemos el tamaño justo.

Cuando quieres agregar un nuevo elemento al array NumPy (o en C) tiene que pedirle al SO que le asigne M bytes a continuación del último elemento array, esto puede ser posible o no dependiendo de si hay memoria contigua sin asignar. Si no es posible, solo queda pedirle al SO un nuevo espacio de memoria de tamaño N x (M + 1) y copiar todo el array a la nueva posición).

Por otro lado, `numpy.ndarray.append` está pensado para siempre retornar una copia del array, no para agregar elementos in-place. Si queremos agregar elemntos in-place podemos usar `numpy.ndarray.resize`. Ésto **no nos asegura que en algún momento no se tenga que copiar el array en memoria** como se ha comentado y no hay forma de solucionar ésto estemos trabajando en NumPy, en C o dónde sea, a no ser que reservemos de antemano memoria de sobra desde el principio. Lo que si nos asegura es que intentará agrandar el array sin copiar nada siempre que sea posible.

Para probar los distintos códigos voya  usar un array aleatorio como éste:

```
array_inicial = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000000, dtype="uint8")
```

Usando `numpy.append`:

```
array_final = np.array([], dtype="uint8")
for n in array_inicial:
    if n != 0:
        array_final = np.append(array_final, n)
```

> %%timeit 40 s ± 465 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Como era de esperar, en cada llamada a `append` se reserva memoria para el array nuevo y se copia todo en la nueva localización...

Puedes intentar varias cosa:

- Usar `numpy.ndearray.resize`:

  ```
  array_final = np.ndarray([], dtype="uint8")
  for n in array_inicial:
      if n != 0:
          array_final.resize(array_final.size + 1)
          array_final[-1] =  n
  ```

  > ```
  > %%timeit 5.4 s ± 118 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  > ```

  Se podría usar una solución intermedia entre esta y la siguiente, usando otro array intermedio como buffer, disminuyendo el número de llamadas  a `resize`.
- Si sabes que como máximo tu array final va a tener el tamaño del original o dos veces más, etc, puedes reservar memoria para este máximo y luego aplicar un resize y quedarte solo con lo usado. Esto puede despilfarrar RAM inicialmente pero evitas las costosas operaciones de copia seguro. Además, el coste en tiempo de CPU de declarar un array sin inicializar es despreciable, solo se reserva memoria y ya está.

  ```
  array_final = np.empty_like(array_inicial)
  index = 0
  for n in array_inicial:
      if n != 0:
          array_final[index] =  n
          index += 1
  array_final.resize(index)
  ```

  > ```
  > %%timeit 3.28 s ± 59.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  > ```

  En este caso el consumo de CPU se debe prácticamente todo al propio ciclo `for`, si no podemos vectorizar la operación (en este ejemplo lógicamente si) no nos queda más remedio que usar la flexibilidad de Python a costa de la perdida de eficiencia.

Comment: Dejé la aplicación en funcionamiento a las 11 y todavía está leyendo y guardando items, para un archivo de 10MG, evidentemente tengo que arreglar esto. El bucle for apenas tiene 5 comparaciones if. Comenzó muy rápido y ahora va lentísimo, con mi viejo cacharro de 4 núcleos y 4GB de RAM. FJSevilla como tú bien explicas en cada append debe reasignar memoria y es lo que lo hace lento.
Tengo curiosidad por saber los resultados, así que esperaré y después, probaré con resize e intentaré asignarle un tamaño inicial al array final antes del bucle. Comentaré los resultados.

Comment: Por cierto, utilizo time.time() para controlar el tiempo total, ¿cómo lo haces para detallarlo tanto?

Comment: Increíblemente hay una diferencia abismal de velocidad de proceso entre asignar primero el espacio de los arrays y no hacerlo, además de no utilizar append. He analizado un fichero con un millón de bytes (1MG) en 101 segundos. Lo cual tampoco es ninguna cosa del otro mundo, teniendo en cuenta que WinRar lo hace en !!un segundo!!. Ahora ya es cuestión de optimizar el algoritmo y poco más. Otra idea sería meterse en camisa de once varas con el código máquina o algún lenguaje más rápido que python, compilado y no interpretado. FJSevilla te marco como respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Con NumPy si quieres optimizar puedes hacerlo con [Cython o con la C API de Python](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html), llevándote los ciclos a C y compilando. Luego llamas a las funciones desde Python como si de funciones Python se tratara y trabajas con tus arrays normalmente... Claro que esto ya no es Python, hay que tener cudadín con tipos, asignación de memoria, desbordamiento de buffer y demás... Eso si, consigues rendimientos muy similares a C puro si sabes lo que te haces.

Comment: @FrankMascarell no había visto tu comentario de más arriba, para medir los tiempos `time.time` no es la mejor opción ni la mas precisa. Es mejor [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), yo por comodidad y porque soy vago XD uso un Notebook de Jupyter/IPython en el mismo Spyder IDE, para esto:  https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit. Colocas todo el código a medir en una celda y el comando "mágico" `%%timeit` en la primera línea, esa es la salida que muestro.

Comment: Hubo un tiempo que estuve leyendo y practicando un poco con C++, pero con el tema de los punteros es una locura. Potente pero peligroso. Después pasé a C# y ahora a Python, y aquí me quedo. ¿Hay alguna manera de convertir un .py en .exe para Windows? Lo siento creo que me estoy saliendo del tema. Le echaré un vistazo a timeit. Saludos.

Comment: Hay varias opciones, cx_freeze, pyinstaller, Nuitka (esta  realmente convierte el código a C/C++ y lo compila) o PyOxider (también sirve para embeber código Rust en Python). Los dos primeros son lo que se conoce como freezer (copian un intérprete y todas las librerías que necesitan y lo empaquetan en un ejecutable).

Comment: Gracias, lo investigaré. :)